# Proof of graph theorem

Tags: graph-theory

Be $G=(V,E)$ single graph, no loops and connected. Prove that G has exactly one cycle if and only if $|V|=|E|$.

Comment: Could you give more context to your question? Maybe what have you already tried or what are you struggling with.

Comment: HINT: You should know a theorem that says that if $G$ is a simple graph, then $|V|=|E|+1$ if and only if $G$ has a certain property. Think about removing an edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the following characterization of a *tree*:

> A simple graph on $n$ vertices (without loops) is a tree if and only if there is a unique path between any two distinct vertices if and only if it is connected and has $n-1$ edges.

Now consider a connected graph $G$ with only one cycle. Deleting one edge $e$ on the cycle cannot disconnect the graph, so the resulting graph is connected and has no cycle ie. is a tree. Hence $G-e$ has $n-1$ edges, so $G$ has $n$ edges.

Conversely suppose we are given a connected graph $G$ with $n=\vert V(G) \vert = \vert E(G) \vert$. By the characterization of trees $G$ has at least one cycle $C$. Pick and delete some edge $e=xy$ on $C$. $G-e$ is still connected and has $n-1$ vertices, hence is a tree. Note that any cycle in $G$ must contain the edge $e=xy$, since $G-e$ is acyclic. But $C-e$ is the unique $x$-$y$-path in $G-e$ yielding that $C$ is the unique cycle in $G$.